# Get all accessed (apache+php)

Tags: php, apache

on my site, I want to log every accessed file, including .js, .jpg files. My .htaccess file is set to ignore .css .js files, so php cant "detect" if those files are required (and it would be very bad for the performance not to ignore those files). Apache logs all accesses, thats right, is there an option from php to get the accessed files from apache?

Answer (score 1):

You can have .htaccess files for each folder.
So each folder has specific rules.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

you've got some (odd) options:

- php-controller for everything, even css etc. Drawback: performance. Gain: better cache-control of css.
- if you're using a filesystem with lastaccess timestamp: scan your dirtree with fileatime(). Drawback is you won't get the count but overtime at least find files that aren't used.

Comment: "php-controller for everything, even css etc. Drawback: performance. Gain: better cache-control of css" yes, thats what I dont want. Isnt there an "apache extension" to communicate with apache?

Comment: When apache is serving css it's not even launching php and since you're not logging css, there's nothing php can do about it later when it's once launched by a .php-script.